# Is smoke sensor safe for eyes / kids?

Tags: led, infrared, smoke-sensor

So I was researching stuff about smoke sensors and I may be paranoid but I was wondering if they were Safe for kids and in general , I read they had infrared LEDS which I heard were very harmful for eyes if looked at directly which I assume the IR LESS are inside and nor visible outside the smoke detector but I was wondering if there was any way the LED can leak out and harm a child since they are curious and like to stare at lights/ etc.. Just got me thinking thanks for the feedback

Comment: Why would IR from a battery powered device (which last years), hence ultra low power be harmful in the first place? How would it pass UL or CE mark certification if it was dangerous?

Comment: There will be far more infrared light from your TV remote control. Have a look at it using your phone's camera which can see it.

Comment: most residential smoke detectors don't use LEDs, they use a radiation source to avoid triggering on grease smoke.

Comment: A radiation source, which is in fact, dangerous if ingested.... yet the devices themselves are generally UL and CE marked, because people shouldn't be poking around inside them.

Comment: If it's one or the other (smoke sensor with LED or no smoke sensor at all) then I'd absolutely choose smoke sensor. Any damage the sensor might possibly do over your child's lifetime is vastly outweighed by making sure you know if your house is on fire and you and your family should get out immediately.

Answer (score 12):

The LED in a smoke detector is safe to look at. Not only that, but the smoke detector is constructed in such a way that the light of this LED does not actually escape the device. It is hidden away in such a way that light can't get in from the outside, as this may disturb the sensor's ability to detect the smoke. This structure works both ways, and hence the light can also not get out.

In other words, they are completely safe and your children will be far safer with a smoke detector around.

Answer (score 5):

Infrared LEDs are perfectly safe to look at. They're what are used in most remote controls, for instance, as well as on many "night vision" surveillance cameras. [Some very bright infrared LEDs can be seen as very dim red light](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321780/if-infrared-not-visible-why-the-red-leds/321970#321970), but even these are not harmful -- and the LEDs in a smoke detector will be much smaller than that.

Comment: So smoke detector is completely safe ? Thanks for the answer as well

Comment: The only danger I can think of would be if a child took out the battery and put it in their mouth. And even that isn't especially hazardous -- more of just a surprise.

Comment: Unless they swallow the battery - not if it is a pp3 but a mercury button type cell...

Comment: Smoke detectors either have 9V blocks or soldered lithium cells.

Comment: no, they are not safe, they contain radioactive materials you don't want a kid eating

Comment: @dandavis -- the OP is referring to a photoelectric type smoke detector, not an ionization type

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I don't have any reason to think OP's even aware of the diff, and given the nature of the inquiry, it's worth mentioning before someone gets sick.

Comment: @duskwuff Putting a battery in your mouth is hazardous. Kids have died from swallowing batteries.

Comment: @kasperd Smoke detectors with replaceable batteries almost always run on a 9V (aka PP3 or 6LR61) battery, which is too large to swallow. You're thinking of button cell batteries, which are much smaller.

Comment: _"Infrared LEDs are perfectly safe to look at."_ - I think this is dangerously misleading; too much IR can damage the eyes just like too much visible light can, but because your eyes don't see it your body doesn't protect itself with pupil contraction or optical reflex. Sure, moderate amounts of IR (nevermind the tiny amount from the smoke sensor) won't be a problem, but if someone puts high-intensity IR LEDs right up to their eyes I'm not so sure. Please edit your answer to include at least some caution.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, IR radiation *can* damage your eyes. However, that doesn't mean that the IR LED within a smoke detector (which has special form as to not let out much of the radiation at all, plus it is inside a plastic case) isn't perfectly safe. It is, by all means, perfectly safe.

The "night-vision" light used in every surveillance camera or webcam with support for enhanced "dark vision" comes from a IR LED and has, depending on model, anywhere from 500 to 2,500 times the power of the LED in a smoke detector. IR flood lights such as the one I'm using to have my garden appear bright as in daylight on the surveillance camera have more like 500,000-1,000,000 times as much.
**None** of these damage your eyes (though the latter *does* irritate night-active insects as they can see the light, alas it also irritates burglars, which is more important to me).

IR light used to be, once upon a time when safety at work was written in small caps, a known source of eye disorders with metal workers. But here, we're talking about, I don't know, 100 *billion* times the radiation intensity of my garden flood light, and exposure over years.
That's nowhere near comparable to the intensity of what's inside a well-sealed smoke detector.

Comment: Do you have sources for the claim that IR radiation can damage your eyes? I'd think that any source releasing enough IR to be dangerous will be so hot and close that it's dangerous anyhow, even without the IR.

Comment: @EricDuminil an obvious example is IR lasers.  No heat, and the distance doesn't matter as they have a collimated beam

Comment: @EricDuminil Given you can melt solder with IR (e.g. infrared reflow oven), you can also cook your eyes too. But that takes an awful lot more energy than you can get out of a smoke detector.

Comment: @EricDuminil I would not suggest looking at the sun through a strong magnifying glass either. That would probably be quite painful, even though the IR emitter is far far away and not dangerously hot.

Comment: @MrGerber: By using a magnifying glass, you make the sun "closer" and hotter to your eye. It's also not 100% IR.

Comment: No, you collect more energy in the same spot, and cook your lens out. With heat radiation = IR. If you are referring to the UV, then just use a UV absorbing lens - most of them are anyway. (And it's not the VIS wavelengths that are cooking your eyes)

Comment: @MrGerber: You might find this article interesting : https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/

Comment: I own the book, thanks. I'm not sure what you're getting at? We could take it to chat, if you like.

Comment: @MrGerber: I was referring to this image in particular : https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/145/linesight.png Using a magnifying glass really is like making the sun closer, but you answered "No".